# What test to perform on my complicated data...?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, friedman-test

I have data that looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to analyze time and num_collisions.  Subjects completed each combination of device/rho/lam/hmd x 6 trials [within subjects design, repeated trials]

There are three different 'device's, 'rho's, and 'lam's with two different 'hmd's.

The results are non-normal.

I would like to be able to compare individual pairings. For example, I'd like to compare [rho=100+headset vs rho=100+monitor] or [rho=300+headset vs rho=100+headset].  I believe an aligned-rank-transform is the way to handle this data, but I run into errors when trying to use ARTool with my dataset.

I posted before ([What test/posthoc test for within-subjects, non-parametric ANOVA? Need help with a complicated analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/556021/what-test-posthoc-test-for-within-subjects-non-parametric-anova-need-help-with)) but running multiple Friedman tests seemed to give results that were too good. Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some additional context?  What are you measuring, what hypothesis are you interested in evaluating?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to measure performance on a task.  The participant walks around trying to avoid obstacles in a virtual reality task with a VR headset or on the computer.  'num_collisions' is a performance metric based on how many times they hit an obstacle.

Comment: Comment limit was reached... 'device' is a simulated device they are looking through with rho and lambda being parameters that distort the view in one of two directions. The goal was to run an ANOVA to see if any of the conditions (device, rho, Lambda, or display type) affect performance (i.e. cause more collisions). Our data is non normal and we have repeated measures AND repeated trials. Someone told me either ART or a generalized linear mixed method  model but ARTool doesn't like my data. The GLMM seems complicated so I want to make sure before I spend more time on this...

Answer (score 0):

So anyone with a basic knowledge of R would have been able to help me here...

You must first convert the column to factor with

```
csv$Column = factor(csv$Column)
```

You can't perform inline conversions within the ART call.

Glad to have it figured out finally, hopefully this can help someone else